# User checked item in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox`. I want to know when the user checked or unchecked an item. I tried using `ItemCheck` event but it fires even when an item is programmatically checked. How can I detect this?

Comment: Try setting CheckOnClick to your CheckedListBox

Comment: @Mate, doesn't work...

Comment: You can add a bool Fields, say, `IsCheckedByCode`, that you set to `true` before you programmatically change an Item's state and reset afterwards. Yes, there's nothing like the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event (user only). But, since it's your code that changes the state, you should know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ItemCheck` event handler is the correct method for detecting when the user ticks or un-ticks an item in the `CheckedListBox`. And yes, it will also fire when the item is checked/unchecked programmitically.

If you don't want the event fired when you set/unset items programmatically, you should remove the event handler before hand.

Assuming your event handler looks like this:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        Debug.Print("Checked");
    }
    else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        Debug.Print("Un-Checked");
    }
}
```

Before you set/unset items programmatically, you should add the line:

```
this.checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= this.checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

and after the items have been set/unset you in code, re-add the event handler with:

```
this.checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += this.checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

Comment: This might lead to missing clicks: if the operator clicks while the software is updating, the click won't be seen

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse - what do you mean "while the software is updating"?

Comment: @Sipo What HaraldCoppoolse means is that if there is a scenario where after the application has loaded, and the user is using the app AND you also update the CheckedListBox in the code, there is a chance that the user can select/deselect an item and this action will be missed IF you don't allow for it. In this case, you have options like disabling the form so no-one can interact with it until the code update is finished.